# Can KNNImputer be used in filling time series data?

Tags: time-series, python, data-imputation, k-nearest-neighbour

I was wondering whether I could fill some null values in a time series dataset about the air quality of India, with knnimputer. Because it seems reasonable to say some days are similar to each other and have same amount of pollution. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

As always, the answer is "it depends". In general, you can use nearest neighbors to input the missing data, but it isn't necessarily the best you can do. For example, say that you have 50 years of data and the nearest neighbor for yesterday is some data point 45 years ago. We know that things like air pollution do not change dramatically, so yesterday's pollution is likely more similar to the day before yesterday than 45 years ago. The same would apply to many features that I guess you could be using like socio-economical indicators, maybe features relating to climate, etc. For time-series data, in many cases, it would make more sense to exploit the fact that we know that the data is autocorrelated, there are trends and seasonality, so tomorrow would be similar to today, but also could be similar to the same day one week ago, or maybe to the same day year ago if there is some kind of yearly seasonality, etc.